# How to extract entities from TravelDirectionsData?

Tags: data, geography, geographics, entity

I am wondering how to extract entities such as states and cities from TravelDistanceData.
For example, given the following example from the documentation, how could I extract the states the route goes through:

```
td = TravelDirections[{Entity[
    "City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Miami", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}]}]
```

My goal is to find a way to figure out the Country Chains Wolfram Challenge.

Comment: Possibly a better way: precompute the border graph from `EntityValue["Country", 
 EntityProperty["Country", "BorderingCountries"], "Dataset"]` and set up a `ShortestPathFunction` with `FindShortestPath` and then query that repeatedly

Comment: how would I set the ShortestPathFunction?

Comment: I tried FindShortestPath[Graph@Normal@data,country1,country2] where data is the dataset, but I got an error.

Comment: A) you need to fix the dataset to work with Graph and b) you should read the docs on `FindShortestPath` because it’s documented there and then come back if you can’t figure it out

Answer (score 1):

```
td = TravelDirections[{Entity[
    "City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Miami", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}]}]

td["Properties"]
```

> ```
> {"Dataset", "ManeuverGrid", "TravelPath", "TravelDistance", \
> "TravelTime"}
> ```

---

To plot the path:

```
tpath = td["TravelPath"]
GeoGraphics[tpath]
```

[image]

---

First attempt using Travel directions is not very satisfying and completely misses a lot of states as it is highway-centric.

```
Union@TextCases[Normal@td["Dataset"][All, "Description"], 
   "AdministrativeDivision"] /. {} -> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{"Florida"}, {"New Hampshire"}, {"New Jersey"}, {"Rhode Island"}, \
> {"Staten Island"}}
> ```

---

A much better approach is to figure out the geo-positions in column 5:

```
locs = Normal@td["Dataset"][All, "StartingPoint"]

Union@Normal@(GeoIdentify["USState", #] & /@ locs) /. {} -> Nothing
```

[image]

Comment: How would I adapt it to run fast enough to be done in 3000 milliseconds for the Wolfram Challenge Country Chains?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
ds = TravelDirections[{Entity[
      "City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
     Entity["City", {"Miami", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}]}]["Dataset"];

states = DeleteDuplicates[
  GeoNearest["USState", #] & /@ Normal[ds[All, "StartingPoint"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I added some more ideas to my question.